# How are Daily Horoscopes Written?

Tags: astrology, tradition, horoscopes

How are daily horoscopes written and published in newspapers and magazines? Can they be same for people under one zodiac sign (i.e *rashi*)

Answer (score 2):

No, they cannot be the same for different people. That is just a way to make money and fool people. I will answer this question from a mathematical point of view.

The daily horoscopes published in newspapers and magazines are based on the Sun sign.

Now, there can be 12 possible sun signs.

The current population of the planet is around 7 billion. Assuming, equal distribution of the 12 signs, each sun sign will have around 600 million people! Statistically, they all cannot have the same events happening to them on the same day (every day).

Actual horoscope making and reading is way more complex. In the birth chart, there are [9 planets, 12 signs and 12 houses](http://www.barbarapijan.com/bpa/bAstrHom.htm). Temporally, there is a system called [Dasha](http://www.barbarapijan.com/bpa/VimshottariDasha/1VimshottariDasha_mainpage.htm) which keeps changing. *This results in a huge number of possible combinations.*

To add to this, I have not included the *subjective* aspect of horoscope reading which makes it a very *intuitive* art.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are wrong, correct prediction is done based on the Maha Dasha and sub-Dasha in which you are currently, including Sade Saat Shani and the positions of those Dasha planets in your Lagna horoscope. Basically they become effective in your lifetime whether in beginning, middle or end of lifetime. Share some dob and i will predict based on horoscope.

Comment: Welcome to the site!!! Please do cite references while answering!